# react js date format using java script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react js for my form. currently i am loading my date to the text box. but currently its show with different format please check this

```
     <Form.Control
            type="text" disabled
            size="sm"
            placeholder=""
            name="termDate"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.termDate}
          />
```

I am setting the value using the code given below:

```
setFieldValue('termDate', dataObj.termDate);
```

when I use the above code, textbox date load as below.
[image]

I need to load this date as 2021-07-07.

How do I format this before loading it to the textbox?

Comment: `setFieldValue('termDate', dataObj.termDate.split('T')[0]);`  I do this but might not be the optimal way

Comment: `dataObj.termDate.substr(0, 10)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com). This oneliner will help

```
moment(dataObj.termDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```